# Recording Square Videos on Android

Tags: android, video, instagram, voice-recording

Please I'm trying to record square videos like instagram. I have reduced the height of my SurfaceView preview. It doesn't 'match_parent' but instead 400dp. However, it's making the preview distorted(looking too wide). Please how do I fix this? Maybe something like the way ImageView uses 'centerCrop' to truncate any part that is outside the view bounds.

This is very important to me please and I'll appreciate any positive input .

Any ideas?  Or third party library for recording square videos﻿

Comment: Use ffmpeg library for square video recording.

Comment: its better to use `TextureView` for a preview and its `setTransform(Matrix transform)` method

Comment: try this its best square camera for me github.com/CrazyOrr/FFmpegRecorder